# If condition issue in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, if-statement

I have a problem with "if condition" in mongodb. I use php here. I have two fields complete_date and available_date. Now I use the below code

```
$obj = $this->mongo_db;
$obj->where(array('status' => 'y'));        
$obj = $obj->where_between("complete_date",$arr['filter_from'],$arr['filter_to']);      
$res = $obj->get('school');
```

My need is to change the complete_date and available_date fields in the above where_between condition based on a condition. Below is my condition,

`if(complete_date < date("Y-m-d H:i"))` then use the `complete_date`
else use the `available_date`
both the two fields are in the collection
how to implement this if condition in the above mongodb query?